# Can not obtain ownership information

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2012-r2

IIS was running on port 80. I created Self Signed Certificates and did the binding for the resources hosted on the server, enabling port 443 for HTTPS. Then later on I had to remove to bindings, as well as the certificates. And disable 443. And now what I find is the even after restarting the web server, it's not really starting.
It is showing as successfully started, but that's not really working.

When I checked the o/p of **netstat -abno**

I got the information "**Can not obtain ownership information**".

I googled for the same. But the results are not satisfying, and I am not really finding any fix for the issue.

Please help. #TIA

Comment: Does the event log say anything interesting?

Comment: From the event log says, "A process serving application pool 'DefaultAppPool' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was "5972."

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment

> From the event log says, "A process serving application pool
>   'DefaultAppPool' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows
>   Process Activation Service. The process id was "5972."

your application pool is having trouble reaching the Windows Process Application Service (WAS).  Make sure that the WAS process is running in services, then go into IIS manager and try to start the application pool.